# how to find the same words in two csv files using Python 3

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm totally new in python but I'm working on a small project.
I have a A file and a B file like below:
[image]

And I want to compare A&B and get the words that in both A&B files.
I've tried several methods but I couldn't solve it anyway.

Can anyone help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear what your desired output is.

Comment: In my example, I want to get 'major', 'stats' since they're both in A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rthomas529 has the right idea, but it gets into a few pitfalls.  It misses cases where there is punctuation, inconsistent capitalization, or lines with multiple words.

```
# Load the files for processing
file_1 = open('f1.txt')
file_2 = open('f2.txt')

# Prep some empty sets to throw words into
words_1 = set()
words_2 = set()

for word in file_1.read().split():
    cleaned_word = ''.join([
        i for i in list(word.lower()) 
        if i.isalpha() or i == "'"
    ])
    if cleaned_word != '': # Just in case!
        words_1.add(cleaned_word)

for word in file_2.read().split():
    cleaned_word = ''.join([
        i for i in list(word.lower()) 
        if i.isalpha() or i == "'"
    ])
    if cleaned_word != '': # Just in case!
        words_2.add(cleaned_word)

similar_words = words_1 & words_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create 2 lists and compare them.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

with open('file1', 'r+') as myfile1:
   for line in myfile1:
      list1.append(line)

with open('file2', 'r+') as myfile2:
   for line in myfile2:
      list2.append(line)

compare = set(list1) & set(list2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use set but it says: TyperError: unsupported operand type(s) for & : 'set' and 'list'. I think I can't 'set' directly since I'm actually comparing a list of lists ([[  ],[  ],[  ],[  ]]) with a list? I don't know whether pandas can do this? or Do I need a for loop by using your method?

Comment: Look at Jordan Singer's answer. I wasn't giving you an in depth enough answer.

Comment: if you have your lists already formatted nicely mapped1 = [i for i in list2 if i in list1] will work for a list in a list. Try it with list1 = [['a', 'x'], ['b', 'x'], ['c', 'x']] list2 = [['a', 'x'], ['a', 'z'], ['b', 'x']] as a test.